# unoconv with --stdin not working

Tags: encoding, utf-8, stdin, unoconv

I am using `unoconv` to convert `docx` to `pdf`. All works great as long as I am passing the document via file name:

```
$ unoconv -f pdf --stdout test.docx
```

But as soon as I am using `--stdin` it doesn't work anymore:

```
$ unoconv -f pdf --stdin --stdout < test.docx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 1275, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 1185, in main
    inputfn = sys.stdin.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 41: invalid start byte
```

It's the same file. Why doesn't this work?

Here is the file: https://nofile.io/f/bKz1zWf745K/test.docx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `--stdin` option doesn't do what one probably thinks it does.

In the error message, the variable name in line 1185 looks suspicious:

```
inputfn = sys.stdin.read()
```

And indeed, checking the [source code](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/blob/master/unoconv), it seems that the text read from STDIN is interpreted as the file *name*, not the file content.

However, the documentation (`man unoconv`) is misleading:

> --stdin
>   Read input file from stdin (filenames are ignored if provided)

This really doesn't sound like interpreting the input as file name.

I suggest that you [file a bug report](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues) about this (maybe first check if there is one already).

Comment: Thanks for your help. You're right. I created a bug report: https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/441